# Historical Timelines

Tags: data-visualization, macos, history

Could anyone recommend good macOS software (either free or low cost) for creating graphics of historical timelines?

I have found [Istoriam](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/istoriam/id1103023088?mt=12) in the macOS App Store, but I'm curious about alternatives, especially with more options for configuring the visuals. Also, it doesn't seem capable of displaying more than one time range/block horizontally.

Here's an example of the sort of graphic I want to produce. Not necessarily so complex, but it should give an indication nonetheless.

[image: example graphic]

Answer (score 1):

https://propublica.github.io/timeline-setter/

TimelineSetter is a tool to create HTML timelines from spreadsheets of events.

TimelineSetter relies on TableFu, as well as the JavaScript libraries Underscore and jQuery. All of these are either installed along with TableSetter, or packaged with the source. It has been tested with jQuery 1.5.1 and Underscore 1.1.5.

Install TimelineSetter through RubyGems on Unix-like OSes:

**gem install timeline_setter**

After TimelineSetter is installed, the timeline-setter command should be available in your shell.

The official home page provides documentation about the csv file format.

Comment: Thank you. It seems however that timeline_setter cannot do date ranges/blocks. (Also, do you have a example graphic by any chance? I couldn’t find one.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TikiToki Desktop](https://www.tiki-toki.com/desktopapp/) if $25 is acceptable.

Comment: Looks good, thank you. Not super cheap, but certainly the sort of thing I want.

Comment: What was your example graphic made with?

Comment: No idea! I grabbed it off Wikipedia. Possibly just with a vector graphic editor...